# Citrix Receiver being slow under OS X 10.9.5

Tags: osx-mavericks, lag, citrix-receiver

I have downloaded the latest Citrix receiver, I am able to run an application fine but it has massive lag.

I tried to solve it with the following link: http://blogs.citrix.com/2013/10/31/citrix-on-osx-10-9-mavericks but doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas? Im so desperate!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. Open the file ~/Library/Application Support/Citrix
   Receiver/Config in a text editor
2. Find the line: [Thinwire3.0]
3. Immediately after [Thinwire3.0] add a new line containing the following text: EnableAtomicDisplay=Off
4. Save the file and close the text editor

Source: http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/339368-mac-109-receiver-not-refreshing-re-drawing/

It is working perfectly now.

Comment: I would still not tag it 'working perfectly' but this certainly improved things quite a lot.